# many sleeping httpd connections

Tags: php, linux, download

i have a downloading website written in php to download from remote servers using curl but the thing is the httpd connections are not terminated they are still in sleeping mod which is killing my server resources, here is the top output

```
top - 20:55:36 up 4 days, 13:41, 1 user, load average: 1.99, 5.73,  
10.47 Tasks: 2207 total, 5 running, 2202 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie Cpu(s): 24.1%us, 1.5%sy, 0.0%ni, 73.3%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 1.1%si,  
0.0%st Mem: 4045976k total, 4000712k used, 45264k free, 1448k buffers Swap: 8385920k total, 2353584k used, 6032336k free, 30336k cached
```

i traced one pid using this `strace -p 22254 -s 80 -o /tmp/debug.lighttpd.txt` i got this output which i'm not sure but it seems to be polling and polling

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10396, 471413333}) = 0
poll([{fd=24, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 725) = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10397, 196905333}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10397, 196955333}) = 0
poll([{fd=24, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10398, 197890333}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10398, 197937333}) = 0
poll([{fd=24, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 1000) = 0 (Timeout)
```

are there any http headers that i'm missing or is there anyway to terminate those connections, any ideas??

here is the php code that i'm using, this is the important part of it

```
header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$fileName);
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n"); 
header("Connection: close\n");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Content-Range: bytes 0-$size2/$size"); 
header("Content-Length: ".$size);

while($start_range <= $end_range) { 
if (connection_status()!=0) return(false); 
if(($start_range + 999999) > $end_range) $range = $start_range.'-'; 
else $range = $start_range.'-'.($start_range + 999999); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fileLocation); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
if ($cookie != false) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
if ($refurl != false) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refurl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE,$range); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1'); 
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
$start_range +=1000000; 

flush(); 
ob_flush();
ob_end_flush();
}
```

Comment: How are we suppose to diagnose this issue without any PHP code? The stack trace is about as useless as not even having one.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: i apologize for that i will credit the answers from now on

Comment: You can go back and accept them too. In fact, it's suggested you do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with http headers keep-alive, the connection was kept alive causing the trouble, here is how i fixed it.

i didn't initiate and close curl every time, instead one curl is initialed and i send http headers defining keep-alive and keep-alive time. this solved my problem

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
while($start_range <= $end_range) { 
    if (connection_status()!=0) return(false); 
    if(($start_range + 999999) > $end_range) $range = $start_range.'-'; 
    else $range = $start_range.'-'.($start_range + 999999); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fileLocation); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Connection: Keep-Alive',
    'Keep-Alive: 300',
    'Cache-Control: no-cache'
    ));
    if ($cookie != false) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
    if ($refurl != false) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $refurl); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RANGE,$range); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1'); 
    $content = curl_exec($ch); 
    echo $content;
    unset($content);
    $start_range +=1000000;     
    flush(); 
    ob_flush();
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Why do you need to keep-alive? Why not just set a CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT?